# Regular expressions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database, sql-server-2008

Im curious if and how you can use regular expressions to find white space in SQL statments.

I have a string that can have an unlimited amount of white space after the actual string.

For example:

```
"STRING  "
"STRING "
```

would match, but

```
 
"STRING A"
"STRINGB"
```

would not.

Right now I have:

```
like 'STRING%'
```

which doesnt quite return the results I would like.

I am using Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

A simple like can find any string with spaces at the end:

```
where col1 like '% '
```

To also allow tabs, carriage returns or line feeds:

```
where col1 like '%[ ' + char(9) + char(10) + char(13) + ']'
```

Per your comment, to find "string" followed by any number of whitespace:

```
where rtrim(col1) = 'string'
```

Comment: So if I needed any number of characters before the white space, would this work? where col1 like 'STRING% '

Comment: That would find a string that starts with STRING, then anything, and ends with a space.

Comment: Ok, I see what your saying. Thank you for your response. How could I modify your first example to allow for a specific string I am looking for, then any number of white space

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
where len(col1) <> len(rtrim(col1))
```

Comment: nice... that had slipped my mind... 
where len(col1)<> len(col1+":")  it is the intent of the approach.  Excellent catch Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Andomar's answer will find the strings for you, but my spidey sense tells me maybe the scope of the problem is bigger than simply *finding* the whitespace.

If, as I suspect, you are finding the whitespace so that you can then clean it up, a simple

```
UPDATE Table1
SET col1 = RTRIM(col1)
```

will remove any trailing whitespace from the column.

Or RTRIM(LTRIM(col1)) to remove both leading and trailing whitespace.

Or REPLACE(col1,' '.'') to remove *all* whitespace including spaces within the string.

Note that RTRIM and LTRIM only work on spaces, so to remove tabs/CRs/LFs you would have to use REPLACE. To remove those only from the leading/trailing portion of the string is feasible but not entirely simple. Bug your database vendor to implement the ANSI SQL 99 standard TRIM function that would make this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
where len(col1 + 'x') <> len(rtrim(col1)) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

BOL provides workarounds for LEN() with trailing spaces : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx

LEN(Column + '_') - 1

or using DATALENGTH